Searching for a way to get unique words from an array of strings
I'm searching for a way to get all sorted unique words in Swift for an array of strings containing sentences
For example:
let complexArray = ["One large dog", "One small dog", "Two small cats"]

Sorted alphabetic result array = ["cats", "dog", "large", "one", "small", "two"]
I've tried using map, flatMap, and Set and can't figure it out

Please show us what you have written so far.

Break it down into parts. Given your complexArray, how would you break it up into words like ["One", "large", "dog", "One", "small", ...]?

So you need to do several steps:

Convert each string into lower case
Break each string into an array of items separated by spaces
Combine the resulting arrays into one big array
Use something to get rid of duplicate strings
Sort the array.

For 1, use String.lowercased(). 
For 2, use String.conponents(separatedBy:). 
For 3, use flatMap. 
For 4, you could convert your array to a set and back to an array. 
For 5, you could use Array.sorted(). 
See if you can work out the code to do each of those steps. Then combine them. If you can't figure it out, post the code you tried and tell us what errors you are getting and we can help you.

Here is the completed code per Duncan C solution
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let complexArray = ["One large dog", "One small dog", "Two small cats"]
    @State var combinedArray:[String] = []
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            getUniqueWords()
        }
    }
    func getUniqueWords() {
        complexArray.forEach { eaString in
            let oneString = eaString.lowercased()
            let oneArray = oneString.components(separatedBy: " ")
            combinedArray.append(contentsOf: oneArray)
        }
        let uniqueElements = Array(Set(combinedArray))//combinedArray.flatMap { $0 }
        let sortedUniqueElements = uniqueElements.sorted()
        print("uniqueElements ", sortedUniqueElements)
    }
}

uniqueElements  ["cats", "dog", "large", "one", "small", "two"]

Or Set(complexArray.flatMap { $0.lowercased().components(separatedBy: .whitespaces) }).sorted()

If you're going to make combinedArray an @State variable you might not want to append individual words to it. That might cause your views to rebuild each time it changes. I would suggest building results array as a local variable and setting combinedArray at the end.

Also, global functions (That operate on variables from their parent scope and change another variable from their parent scope) are not good practice because the have hidden side-effects and they are not testable. I'd suggest writing a function that takes a complexArray as an input and returns a sorted array of words as output.
